# PDFKit bug, need to disable UIMenuItems

Tags: uimenucontroller, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I am trying to disable UIMenuItems in PDFKit. I have implemented

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

But MenuItems **Copy** and **Select All** are still active.  The main reason I want to disable them is because **Select All** causes fatal memory errors on larger pdf documents.

> malloc: can't allocate region

I have submitted a bug report, but in the meantime I need to disable the menu item.

Note: if pdfDocument.string is large enough, any of the below calls will cause a crash.

1. pdfView.selectAll()
2. UIMenuController.selectAll
3. let string = pdfDocument.string

Answer (score 2):

I needed to override **canPerformAction** on the actual PDFView.  I was doing it in my VC.

```
class MyPDFView: PDFView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```